# RecyclerView change items layout during scroll

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, scrollview, adapter

I am having a requirement to implement a recyclerView with items that have a space between them. While scrolling down, the space should be smaller and smaller.

Using a collapsing layout etc so I am able to get a floating number of a position the only issue is how to change layout of the items programatically after they are already visible on the screen

Comment: Past your code of adapter class

Comment: @MohammadAli currently its only a basic adapter with basics here, having layout with one textView and some margin and settings some random text to it until i figure out the approach. I already look at the getRecycledViewPool().clear() method of recycler witch should force it to redraw but I am almost sure it will create a flushing effect. Basically I have a float value in adapter/fragment which I can update based on scrollPosition and based on That i would like to resize/change margin or something like that